# upload photos from the database to the carousel

Tags: django, ajax

How can I make sure that when uploading photos to the database, the slides in the carousel are updated without reloading the page? 
is it even possible to implement this with ajax?

views.py

```
def index(request):
    time_change = Time.objects.get(id=1).time_for_change_slied * 1000  
    image_list = Image.objects.filter(bool_field=True).order_by('number_of_slaid')
    return render(request, 'prezents/index.html', {'image_list': image_list, 'time_change':time_change})
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="{{time_change}}" data-pause="false">

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for a in image_list %}
          {% if forloop.first %}
    <div class="carousel-item active ">
      {% if a.image_prezents %}
      <img class="d-block " src="{{a.image_prezents.url}}" alt="first">
      {% endif %}

    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="carousel-item">
      {% if a.image_prezents %}
      <img class="d-block " src="{{a.image_prezents.url}}" alt="second">
      {% endif %}

    </div>
    {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: @Вадим-Шаройкин the fact that Django templates are resolved from server-side and then shown in the UI, it would eventually only come down to use Ajax; for a seamless update to the carousel and it can't happen that you can still perform this Asynchronously while not using the concept of Ajax. `You need to first let us know why do you don't want to use Ajax? Is it a limitation to your website?`

Comment: @solarissmoke I asked if this can be done using ajax. I used ajax to submit forms, but don't understand how to use it in a carousel

Comment: @NagarajTantri I did not say that you can not use ajax. It is quite suitable, but I don’t understand how to use it to get data from a database in a carousel

Comment: Don't realy easy to understand. But i think you can use ajax to be sure the upload work, cause if you use REST API django will send you back a request with some status like 200 / 404 and that tell you it's save or not in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on your comment you already know how to use ajax to post data so here I give you example how to updating the carousel without reloading a page with ajax.

Firstly you need to make a view that'll return JSON response (e.g):

```
class CarouselList(View):
def get(self, request):
    carousel = list(Carousel.objects.filter(
        bool_field=True).order_by('number_of_slaid').values())
    data = dict()
    data['carousel'] = carousel
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I use class base view on example above don't forget to update the url:

```
path('carousel/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="carousel.html"),
     name='carousel_home'),
path('carousel/list', CarouselList.as_view(), name='carousel_list'),
```

and your template should look like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block main %}
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval=""
    data-pause="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner">

    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block extrajs %}
<script src="{% static 'main/carousel.js'%}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

finally make the main part that'll get the data asycronusly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
GetData();
setInterval(GetData, 60000);
});

function GetData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/carousel/list',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            let div = '';
            data.carousel.forEach((crsl, index) => {
                $("#carouselExampleIndicators").attr("data-interval", crsl.time * 1000);
                div +=
                    ((index == 0) ? `<div class="carousel-item" active >` : `<div class="carousel-item">`) +
                    `<img class="d-block" src="` + crsl.url + `"></div>`;
            })
            $(".carousel-inner").html(div);
        },
    });
}
```

this `setInterval(GetData, 60000);` function will update or get the data from your database every minute (1000 = 1s)

This example isn't base on your actual models but I hope this make sense.